# GCM downstream messaging JSON format for iOS

Tags: ios, json, swift, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I have an swift/iOS9 application using GCM for it's notifications (WIP).

Application authorisations OK.
Certificates are OK.
Configuration file OK.
Everything is configured on the Apple's developpers portal for development.

This function is called when a notification is received.

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
  GCMService.sharedInstance().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo);
  print(userInfo.debugDescription)
}
```

**Problem**

I can only detect a notification in the previously described function when the server send the following format, and it 'works' because i have a breakpoint to detect it, else nothing happen.

```
{
  "registration_ids" : ["regId"],
  "data" :
   {
      "to" : "regId",
      "notification" : 
      {
         "sound" : "default",
         "badge" : "2",
         "title" : "anyTitle",
         "body" : "anyMessage" 
      }
   }
}
```

The person in charge of the webservices made this for me, and it duplicated the existing Android one (Is "registration_ids" any usefull?).

Since the behaviour wasn't the expected one, we tried this from GCM website :

{
  "to" : "regId",
  "content_available" : true,
  "notification" : {
    "body" : "great match!",
    "title" : "Portugal vs. Denmark"
    }
}

The message create an error server side (invalid format for GCM?)

***Do we miss something obvious?***

Requests are post and headers/url:

```
https://gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm/send
Content-Type:application/json
Authorization:key=AIzaSyZ-1u...0GBYzPu7Udno5aA
```

**EDIT**

Adding the log of the working and non working one.

```
{  
   "registration_ids":[  
      "regId"
   ],
   "data":{  
      "to":"regId",
      "notification":{  
         "sound":"default",
         "badge":"2",
         "title":"testNotif",
         "body":"welcome in the Showcase Apple owner"
      }
   }
}
```

And

```
Exchange[
Id                  ID-FR-LIL-D00184-54996-1457452459441-0-5
ExchangePattern     InOnly
Headers             {Accept=text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,​*/*​;q=0.8, Accept-Encoding=gzip, deflate, Accept-Language=fr-fr, Authorization=key=AIzaSyAB_E2Op0GqShCmCmh_6ZxnwrFKoXOaIHU, beaconId=46589-47438, breadcrumbId=ID-talend2-48271-1456928459992-11-173, Cache-Control=max-age=0, CamelHttpMethod=POST, CamelHttpPath=, CamelHttpQuery=custLogin=alex@cgi.com&beaconId=46589-47438&regId=khjGINhshr4:APA91bGXuzrC3tU_jkBMZGCziqIwA9wKv1B-U4acxy68sQxvChJQvKb187o863CzKJyop1AwhP0BNo7I2SJJiWdrtnHFC42LxcBQzOo2Ah868xPde9TBFmj_FLVG8rhyH4Yl48zuQMCJ, CamelJmsDeliveryMode=2, CamelRedelivered=false, CamelRedeliveryCounter=0, CamelServletContextPath=/setBeaconEvent, Connection=keep-alive, Content-Type=application/json, custLogin=, dateEvent=20160308172331, deviceType=ios, DNT=1, Host=192.168.1.239, JMSCorrelationID=null, JMSDeliveryMode=2, JMSDestination=queue://Q.NOTIFIER, JMSExpiration=0, JMSMessageID=ID:FR-LIL-D00184-64570-1457442695117-1:52:1:1:1, JMSPriority=4, JMSRedelivered=false, JMSReplyTo=null, JMSTimestamp=1457454212345, JMSType=null, JMSXGroupID=null, JMSXUserID=null, regId=khjGINhshr4:APA91bGXuzrC3tU_jkBMZGCziqIwA9wKv1B-U4acxy68sQxvChJQvKb187o863CzKJyop1AwhP0BNo7I2SJJiWdrtnHFC42LxcBQzOo2Ah868xPde9TBFmj_FLVG8rhyH4Yl48zuQMCJ, User-Agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_3) AppleWebKit/601.4.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.0.3 Safari/601.4.4}
BodyType            String
Body                {"registration_ids":["khjGINhshr4:APA91bGXuzrC3tU_jkBMZGCziqIwA9wKv1B-U4acxy68sQxvChJQvKb187o863CzKJyop1AwhP0BNo7I2SJJiWdrtnHFC42LxcBQzOo2Ah868xPde9TBFmj_FLVG8rhyH4Yl48zuQMCJ"],"to":"khjGINhshr4:APA91bGXuzrC3tU_jkBMZGCziqIwA9wKv1B-U4acxy68sQxvChJQvKb187o863CzKJyop1AwhP0BNo7I2SJJiWdrtnHFC42LxcBQzOo2Ah868xPde9TBFmj_FLVG8rhyH4Yl48zuQMCJ", "content_available": true, "notification":{"title": "testNotif","body": "welcome in the Showcase Apple owner" }}
]
Stacktrace
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
org.apache.camel.component.http.HttpOperationFailedException: HTTP operation failed invoking https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send?custLogin=alex@cgi.com&beaconId=46589-47438&regId=khjGINhshr4:APA91bGXuzrC3tU_jkBMZGCziqIwA9wKv1B-U4acxy68sQxvChJQvKb187o863CzKJyop1AwhP0BNo7I2SJJiWdrtnHFC42LxcBQzOo2Ah868xPde9TBFmj_FLVG8rhyH4Yl48zuQMCJ with statusCode: 400
```

**EDIT2**

Thanks to Arthur advices, the notification leaves the server without error now, and I receive it.

Current format is :

```
{  
  "to":"regId",
  "data":{  
     "notification":{  
        "sound":"default",
        "badge":"2",
        "title":"testNotif",
        "body":"welcome in the Showcase Apple owner"
     }
  }
}
```

The remaining problem is that `didReceiveRemoteNotification fetchCompletionHandler` don't receives it if app is in background.
Also `didReceiveRemoteNotification` receives it when app is foreground, but if I don't display it nothing happen.

I am supposed to call something to have the 'system style' notification? Is it ready out of the box if the format is correct?

I can't find informations about this over the web.

Comment: The object that you tried from the documentation seems correct, could you provide the full http request that you are making to GCM.

Comment: Just edited @ArthurThompson. Is that what you wanted?

Comment: You seem to be using reg_ids and to together. You should use be using to (reg_ids works but is not recommended), you should never use them both. In the initial example to is within data so it is probably ignored but in the second example to and reg_ids are siblings, I think that is the format issue.

Comment: @ArthurThompson that seem logical, thanks for pointing this out! I'll try this tomorow.

Comment: Well @ArthurThompson, if you wanna publish this as an answer, it worked. You are the hero of the day, thank you. Everything looks fine, except I still have no "system notification". There is no automatic apple style notification, I don't know if I have to do anything to enable it

Comment: Ok I updated my question with more sub questions

Comment: Notification messages are only displayed when the app is in the background. Try using the high priority field to make a notification show. iOS does not guarantee delivery of messages. Note that high priority should only be used when user interaction is required, but you can use it during testing.

Comment: Ok, and what about the notification parameters, like sound and badge (type? banner etc)

Comment: Even now I setted the alert parameter in the json but still nothing appearing on the phone. I really dont understand. And I can't find a proper example out there :/

Comment: Have you tried the sample on github? github.com/googlesamples/google-services/tree/master/ios/gcm

Comment: Yes I did, always the first thing to do. Problem is they only show client side. Nothing shown looking like what the server send, and I think it's where lies the problem

Comment: The only difference with the doc is that I implemented onTokenChange() in a class extenssion, as soons as the server is back I change that

Comment: Please don't add the solution to the question. A question should remain a question. You can post the solution *as an answer* to your own question, there's no problem with that. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so, after all the only problem was the JSON format :

```
{  
  "to":"regId",
  "notification":{  
     "sound":"default",
     "badge":"2",
     "title":"testNotif",
     "body":"welcome in the shop Apple owner"
  }
}
```

This way the notification is processed by APNS and arrive refined in the correct format.

Answer (score 0):

So when you use the first format you mentioned, you receive the notification (the app stops at the breakpoint)? My only idea is that maybe your app is in foreground when you receive the notification? It should be in the background or closed otherwise you won't notice anything.

Comment: I don't think so, I tried to receive it in background too