# How to get push notification when app is not running/app is terminated

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications, terminate, system-tray

I have tried 
"Setting up a GCM Client App on iOS" from Google developers.
My app has an android version and the server sends push notifications successfully to Android. In ios, I can retrieve the message to didRecieveRemoteNotification function.It looks like below when printed,

```
aps: {
    alert =     {
        body = tyyy;
        title = "2 is going out at 03/24/2016 15:02:48";
    };
    badge = 2;
    sound = default;
}
```

It receives this message when the app is in foreground and background. Nothing is shown in system tray when app is background.

When app is terminated and server is sending push notifications, I receive nothing, no activity shown.

My code is as below.

AppDelegate.swift

```
import UIKit

 @UIApplicationMain



class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, GGLInstanceIDDelegate,  GCMReceiverDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?

var connectedToGCM = false
var subscribedToTopic = false
var gcmSenderID: String?
var registrationToken = "AIzaSy-.....-11bSP6v72UvyKY"
var registrationOptions = [String: AnyObject]()

let registrationKey = "onRegistrationCompleted"
let messageKey = "onMessageReceived"
let subscriptionTopic = "/topics/global"


func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey: "APP_RUNNING")


    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    // [START_EXCLUDE]
    // Configure the Google context: parses the GoogleService-Info.plist, and initializes
    // the services that have entries in the file
    var configureError:NSError?
    GGLContext.sharedInstance().configureWithError(&configureError)
    assert(configureError == nil, "Error configuring Google services: \(configureError)")
    gcmSenderID = GGLContext.sharedInstance().configuration.gcmSenderID
    // [END_EXCLUDE]
    // Register for remote notifications
    if #available(iOS 8.0, *) {
        let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
        UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound], categories: nil)
        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    } else {
        // Fallback
        let types: UIRemoteNotificationType = [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound]
        application.registerForRemoteNotificationTypes(types)
    }

    // [END register_for_remote_notifications]
    // [START start_gcm_service]
    let gcmConfig = GCMConfig.defaultConfig()
    gcmConfig.receiverDelegate = self
    GCMService.sharedInstance().startWithConfig(gcmConfig)
    // [END start_gcm_service]

    application.registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound],categories: nil))

    if let options = launchOptions {
        if let notification = options[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey] as? UILocalNotification {
            if let userInfo = notification.userInfo {

                // do something neat here
            }
        }
    }

    return true
}

func subscribeToTopic() {
    // If the app has a registration token and is connected to GCM, proceed to subscribe to the
    // topic
    if(registrationToken != "" && connectedToGCM) {
        GCMPubSub.sharedInstance().subscribeWithToken(self.registrationToken, topic: subscriptionTopic,
            options: nil, handler: {(error:NSError?) -> Void in
                if let error = error {
                    // Treat the "already subscribed" error more gently
                    if error.code == 3001 {
                        print("Already subscribed to \(self.subscriptionTopic)")
                    } else {
                        print("Subscription failed: \(error.localizedDescription)");
                    }
                } else {
                    self.subscribedToTopic = true;
                    NSLog("Subscribed to \(self.subscriptionTopic)");
                }
        })
    }
}

func application( application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken
    deviceToken: NSData ) {

        // [END receive_apns_token]
        // [START get_gcm_reg_token]
        // Create a config and set a delegate that implements the GGLInstaceIDDelegate protocol.
        let instanceIDConfig = GGLInstanceIDConfig.defaultConfig()
        instanceIDConfig.delegate = self
        // Start the GGLInstanceID shared instance with that config and request a registration
        // token to enable reception of notifications
        GGLInstanceID.sharedInstance().startWithConfig(instanceIDConfig)
        registrationOptions = [kGGLInstanceIDRegisterAPNSOption:deviceToken,
            kGGLInstanceIDAPNSServerTypeSandboxOption:true]
        GGLInstanceID.sharedInstance().tokenWithAuthorizedEntity(gcmSenderID,
            scope: kGGLInstanceIDScopeGCM, options: registrationOptions, handler: registrationHandler)
        // [END get_gcm_reg_token]


}

// [START receive_apns_token_error]
func application( application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError
    error: NSError ) {
        print("Registration for remote notification failed with error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        // [END receive_apns_token_error]
        let userInfo = ["error": error.localizedDescription]
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(
            registrationKey, object: nil, userInfo: userInfo)
}


// [START ack_message_reception]
func application( application: UIApplication,
    didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
        print("Notification received: \(userInfo)")
        // This works only if the app started the GCM service
        GCMService.sharedInstance().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo);
        // Handle the received message
        // [START_EXCLUDE]
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("reloadTableEvent", object: nil)
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(messageKey, object: nil,
            userInfo: userInfo)
        // [END_EXCLUDE]
}

func application( application: UIApplication,
    didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject],
    fetchCompletionHandler handler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
        print("Notification received: \(userInfo)")
        // This works only if the app started the GCM service
        GCMService.sharedInstance().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo);
        // Handle the received message
        // Invoke the completion handler passing the appropriate UIBackgroundFetchResult value
        // [START_EXCLUDE]
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(messageKey, object: nil,
            userInfo: userInfo)
        handler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.NoData);
        // [END_EXCLUDE]
}
// [END ack_message_reception]

func registrationHandler(registrationToken: String!, error: NSError!) {
    if (registrationToken != nil) {
        self.registrationToken = registrationToken
        print("Registration Token: \(registrationToken)")
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setValue(registrationToken, forKey: "registrationToken")
        self.subscribeToTopic()
        let userInfo = ["registrationToken": registrationToken]
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(
            self.registrationKey, object: nil, userInfo: userInfo)
    } else {
        print("Registration to GCM failed with error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        let userInfo = ["error": error.localizedDescription]
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(
            self.registrationKey, object: nil, userInfo: userInfo)
    }
}

// [START on_token_refresh]
func onTokenRefresh() {
    // A rotation of the registration tokens is happening, so the app needs to request a new token.
    print("The GCM registration token needs to be changed.")
    GGLInstanceID.sharedInstance().tokenWithAuthorizedEntity(gcmSenderID,
        scope: kGGLInstanceIDScopeGCM, options: registrationOptions, handler: registrationHandler)
}
// [END on_token_refresh]

// [START upstream_callbacks]
func willSendDataMessageWithID(messageID: String!, error: NSError!) {
    if (error != nil) {
        // Failed to send the message.
    } else {
        // Will send message, you can save the messageID to track the message
    }
}

func didSendDataMessageWithID(messageID: String!) {
    // Did successfully send message identified by messageID
}
// [END upstream_callbacks]

func didDeleteMessagesOnServer() {
    // Some messages sent to this device were deleted on the GCM server before reception, likely
    // because the TTL expired. The client should notify the app server of this, so that the app
    // server can resend those messages.
}

func applicationWillResignActive(application: UIApplication) {
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}

func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {

    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(false, forKey: "APP_RUNNING")

    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.

    GCMService.sharedInstance().disconnect()
    // [START_EXCLUDE]
    self.connectedToGCM = false
    // [END_EXCLUDE]
}

func applicationWillEnterForeground(application: UIApplication) {

    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey: "APP_RUNNING")

    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}

func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {

    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey: "APP_RUNNING")

    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.

    // Connect to the GCM server to receive non-APNS notifications
    GCMService.sharedInstance().connectWithHandler({(error:NSError?) -> Void in
        if let error = error {
            print("Could not connect to GCM: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        } else {
            self.connectedToGCM = true
            print("Connected to GCM")
            // [START_EXCLUDE]
            self.subscribeToTopic()
            // [END_EXCLUDE]
        }
    })
}

func applicationWillTerminate(application: UIApplication) {

    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(false, forKey: "APP_RUNNING")

    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
}

func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveLocalNotification notification: UILocalNotification) {
    if let userInfo = notification.userInfo {
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(
            "LoadEventViewController", object: nil, userInfo: userInfo)
    }
}




}
```

ViewController, popping local notification

```
func scheduleLocal(message: String) {
    let settings = UIApplication.sharedApplication().currentUserNotificationSettings()

    if settings!.types == .None {
        let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Can't schedule", message: "Either we don't have permission to schedule notifications, or we haven't asked yet.", preferredStyle: .Alert)
        ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil))
        presentViewController(ac, animated: true, completion: nil)
        return
    }

    // create a corresponding local notification
    let notification = UILocalNotification()
    notification.alertBody = message // text that will be displayed in the notification
    notification.alertAction = "open" // text that is displayed after "slide to..." on the lock screen - defaults to "slide to view"
    notification.fireDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 0) // todo item due date (when notification will be fired)
    notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName // play default sound
    notification.userInfo = ["UUID": 1, ] // assign a unique identifier to the notification so that we can retrieve it later
    notification.category = "TODO_CATEGORY"
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notification)
}
```

I have 2 questions,

1. Is it possible to receive and show push notification even when app is in terminated state? If so, how?
2. Have I done something wrong in the code?

Comment: 1) Yes is it possible
2) You should format your code for more readability

Comment: Have you configured all the necessary stuff on apple developper? Do you have the certificates? You need both GCM and Apple developper configured. When I implemented my notifications with GCM on iOS i had trouble to implement background notification. This was du to the fact that the format your server send you must be precise. I can point you to my qestion. http://stackoverflow.com/q/35873147/1585121

Comment: When your app is terminated or in background, that's the OS that shows the notification for you.

Comment: What environment of push notification that you create? Sandbox or Production? And you code does not handle the message from APN Server

Comment: What do you mean by "you code does not handle the message from APN Serve"

I got this to work when app is in background by referring to Mayerz link. But still no notification shown when app is running and terminated.

Edited the question for clear code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is your push notification JSON?

```
aps: { "content-available" = 1; }
```

If yes, then you are sending a silent push. Silent push means that the user get's no visual notification, just the app delegate callback of your app is called. Remove the content-available tag and pass a message text instead.

If the App is in the foreground iOS does not show a push notification, but just calls the delegate. Then you can show an Alert View or something else you prefer.

Or you can show this: https://github.com/avielg/AGPushNote

Regarding the state "terminated by user", here the Apple doc (for silent push):

[Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:)

> Use this method to process incoming remote notifications for your app.
>   Unlike the application:didReceiveRemoteNotification: method, which is
>   called only when your app is running in the foreground, the system
>   calls this method when your app is running in the foreground or
>   background. In addition, if you enabled the remote notifications
>   background mode, the system launches your app (or wakes it from the
>   suspended state) and puts it in the background state when a remote
>   notification arrives. However, the system does not automatically
>   launch your app if the user has force-quit it. In that situation, the
>   user must relaunch your app or restart the device before the system
>   attempts to launch your app automatically again.

Comment: Thanks. Done. Still, when app is in running state, no notification is triggered. Same when terminated state. When app is in back ground/phone is locked, push notifications are shown successfully.

Any idea?

Comment: what i receive now is this,

 aps: {
    alert =     {
        body = tyyy;
        title = "2 is going out at 03/24/2016 15:02:48";
    };
    badge = 2;
    "content-available" = 1;
    sound = default;
}

still, when the app is in running state or when terminated,no push notifications shown. only when app is in background the push notifications are shown. I can not figure out why for one state works and for other it does not

Comment: I'm not asking about relaunching the app, I'm asking the question regarding why push notification is not shown in system tray when in terminated state and running state

Comment: Did you read my answer? I already answered this. No push notification is shown in running and terminated state. This is how it is, iOS behaves like this. This is the correct behavior.

Comment: But apps like gmail,facebook sends push notifications even when they are in either running state or terminated state. How do they do it?

Comment: They do not send  "content-available" = 1, like you. You are triggering a silent push. I already wrote to remove the content-available tag.

Comment: Try this payload: {"aps": { "alert": "Test notification." }}

Answer (score -5):

If you didn't did yet, register on Apple developper and configure your app for receiving push notifications. You have to pay a subscription to do so (99$/year).

GCM send message directly to your app when it is in foreground, but during background GCM rely on APNs (Apple Push Notification services) to reach your device.

Due to this, the format of the message sent by your server to GCM must be precisely formatted, [this finally worked for me](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35938144/1585121).

Comment: APNs is required for both of the foreground or background Push notification . No server can directly send notification to apple mobile but through Apple's APNs